# What is this kind of visualization called: lots of squares of different sizes arranged in a square/rectangular bucket

Tags: information-graphics, data-visualisation, information-design

I've seen this on a couple of sites visualizing blockchains - the transactions in a block.  Unlike a treemap the items are not from a hierarchy, represented by nested rectangles in the visualization.

In this visualization each item is independent and has two weights.  One weight controls the *size* of the square, and the other controls, generally, the position of the square. That is, under the second weight the "larger" weighted items are more to the top and right than the others.  Generally.

The examples I've seen clearly come from a library which includes very nice animations of new items coming in, and low weight items (the second weight) being removed.  And a key feature of these animations - which I would like to learn how it works! - is that as items are added and removed, according to their two weights, the disruption of the items already in the set are minimized visually.

But I don't even know what this kind of visualization is called so I can't search for it.  So I'd like to know the name.  (And if you happen to know a commonly-used library that *provides* such a visualization, I'd like to know that too, unless it's against the rules of this site.)

[image: some kind of visualization of a set of items, each with two weights]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not everything has a specific name. Just use descriptive words instead. For example, "random square mosaic/tessellation". As for animation/video software questions, these are generally off-topic here.

Comment: Another possibly helpful term: square packing (without rotation)

Comment: I think this is just a one-level treemap, but modified for squares: this might explain the ragged left. See also one-level circlular packing which is a circular tree map which could be modified to render the bounding box of the circle. Oddly enough, the image above has rectangles at the left edge presumably due to a frame constraint.

Comment: at the left those are cut-off squares that really belong in the container but "don't fit" the square, at least the way it is packed.  (I've determined this by watching these animated for quite awhile.)

Comment: in the 3D DCC word it's often referred to as dynamic packing volume chart - in the IT world it's a non-hierarchical tree diagram, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably call this a *volume chart* or a *block chart*, but ultimately this would fall under the general *charts* category, of which there are many styles: the more popular bar charts and pie charts, and other unnamed charts styles, all showing data sections of a larger amount.

You can also just simply call this an *infographic*.